# converting string to date using TO_DATE for MM/DD/YY gives wrong values for dates before 1970 [snowflake-cloud-data-platform]

Tags: sql, date, select, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, date-arithmetic

Trying to convert a date string 03/31/69 to 1969-03-31 standard date format using TO_DATE function.

```
SELECT TO_DATE('03/31/69', 'MM/DD/YY');
```

Expected value was 1969-03-31 but I am getting 2069-03-31.

please let me know how to handle the century correctly for MM/DD/YY formats in snowflake.

This works fine for dates **after 1970**. It returns the correct century information. Only for dates **before 1970 its converting to 21st century**. Please let me know if this is a known behavior. If so how to convert such formats to standard date format?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Snowflake, how `YY` is interpreted depends on [the `TWO_DIGIT_CENTURY_START` session parameter](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#label-two-digit-century-start), which defaults to 1970.

To get the result that you want for your input data, you would need to alter the parameter to a value that is not greater than 1969:

```
ALTER SESSION SET TWO_DIGIT_CENTURY_START = 1950;
SELECT TO_DATE('03/31/69', 'MM/DD/YY');
```

Comment: thanks . If i set this to 1900 will TO_DATE be able to handle 03/31/1901 and 03/31/2001 as both will have 03/31/01 in MM/DD/YY format? Any suggestion on how to set the TWO_DIGIT_CENTURY_START?